# Azure virtual Dekstop - attached disk has hard limit of 20 for shared users, how can I set this higher?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, windows-11

When more than 20 user are logged in, they cannot access this folder anymore due to this limit.

And I cannot set the limit higher than 20.

You can access this when you go to:

- disk -> then a folder
- properties
- sharing
- advanced sharing
  -> share this folder -> there is the limit

One screeshot from the VM is in german and i added one example in english.

[image]

[image]

The VM image is Windows 11 Multi-session.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried the same in my environment created Azure virtual desktop like below:***

Created host pool, workspace application group in virtual desktop.

[image]

[image]

In virtual desktop when I try to check the user limit in shared folder, I got the same limit.

[image]

***Note***: According to the [Microsoft forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/95b6c143-f769-472c-a52f-df845b0642ea/increase-maximum-number-of-connections-limit-for-a-shared-folder#:%7E:text=Solution:%20Create%20more%20than%20one%20share%20for%20the,-%20Maximum%20allowed%20should%20be%20selected%20%2820%20users%29.) Software licensing conditions place a limitation on the number of users who can access a shared folder. As designed by Azure you can set only 20 users can't increase users to have access to the licensed of shared folder.

Alternatively, you can create another shared folder, two shares that are linked to the same folder user can connect with the other if they are denied access to one.

[image]

[image]

Additionally, instead of virtual desktop if you are using remote desktop attached disk limit of shared users you can increased more like below.

[image]